# hdf5 file cannot be open or fokageund by python distribution package

Tags: python, h5py

I am using Anaconda python distribution package for some hdf5 file analysis. The package comes with numpy, matplotlib, scipy and h5py. 
Today I downloaded a hdf5 file and saved it in a directory whose path is /home/trina/Pictures/ligoData. In the same directory I saved a file plot_strain.py file which should read and execute the hdf5 file.

My program looks like this.

```
#----------------------
# Import needed modules
#----------------------
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import h5py

#-------------------------
# Open the File
#-------------------------
fileName = 'H-H1_LOSC_4_V1-815411200-4096.hdf5'
dataFile = h5py.File(fileName, 'r')

#----------------------
# Explore the file
#----------------------
for key in dataFile.keys():
    print key
```

But when I try to execute the .py in anaconda, with

```
>>> execfile('/home/trina/Pictures/ligoData/plot_strain.py')
```

the error message occurs

```
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Aug 21 2014, 18:22:21) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> execfile('/home/trina/Pictures/ligoData/plot_strain.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/trina/Pictures/ligoData/plot_strain.py", line 12, in <module>
    dataFile = h5py.File(fileName, 'r')
  File "/home/trina/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 222, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl)
  File "/home/trina/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 79, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDONLY, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5f.pyx", line 71, in h5py.h5f.open (h5py/h5f.c:1797)
IOError: Unable to open file (Unable to open file: name = 'h-h1_losc_4_v1-815411200-4096.hdf5', errno = 2, error message = 'no such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

Can you please tell me the reason of this error? It seems it cannot find the file at all though they are located in the same folder called ligoData.

Answer (score 2):

Try providing the full, absolute path in plot_strain.py for the filename variable. The execfile statement just reads and executes the lines in the given file, so it is probably searching within the directory you started the anaconda prompt from.